# Reddit post API

Tags: api, curl, submit, reddit

I am trying to follow the reddit api, as outlined here:

https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API

Logging in using curl is not a problem:

```
curl -d user=user -d passwd=pass -c Cookie.txt http://www.reddit.com/api/login
```

Which gives me a cookie, in which (I assume) contains my user mod-hash:

```
4029916%2C2010-04-30T22%3A51%3A52%2C1243925043100000000000000000000000000000
```

Next I am trying to post, using:

```
curl -d uh=4029916%2C2010-04-30T22%3A51%3A52%2C1243925043100000000000000000000000000000 -d sr=test -d title=test -d r=test -c Cookie.txt http://www.reddit.com/api/submit
```

However, I receiver an error:

```
[".error.USER_REQUIRED"]
```

Can someone explain what I have done incorrectly/how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Look here: https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API%3A-login

Notice that cookie isn't the same thing as modhash.